# how do I return data from a node.js request call? (undefined is not a function)

Tags: node.js

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a callback somewhere here:

from tools.js:

```
exports.getServerPermalink = function(username, callback) {
requestURL = config.apiServer+ username + myUrl
request(requestURL, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    list = JSON.parse(response.body);
    console.log(list);
    newPermalink = list[0].permalink;
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
  callback(null, newPermalink);
  });
}
```

it's called here, my main file (tools.js is included):

```
newPermalink = tools.getServerPermalink(checkSession.username);
res.redirect('/'+ newPermalink) ;
```

but I get the error "undefined is not a function" pointing to

```
      callback(null, newPermalink);
```

when I try to run it.

Any pointers to examples for the "require" module that don't just console.log stuff would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`callback` seems to be undefined because you didn't pass it to your modules method

should be like this:

```
tools.getServerPermalink(checkSession.username, function(argument, newPermalink){
    res.redirect('/'+ newPermalink) ;
});
```

Also `tools.getServerPermalink()`doesn't directly return the url (it does not return anything, as the internal request is asynchronous) but passes it as the second argument to your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

your exports.getServerPermalink is a function defined taking 2 arguments but when you call it, you are only passing in one: newPermalink = tools.getServerPermalink(checkSession.username);